# How use crystal report with angularjs2 and Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, angular, crystal-reports

I need access crystal report with angularjs2 and Nodejs.

Please provide any suggestion.

Thank you for giving your time.

Comment: I need users to build reports and output to screen, printer and standard file formats such as Excel, PDF, CSV, Word etc.